# R function/loop: when a numeric variable falls below a value (ex. 40), how long does it take to get back above 40?

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a reproducible/automated function in R that captures the "recovery rate" of a specific numeric variable. This variable "SNR_kHz" varies between -17 and 77 kHz, but also has a categorically related variable called "SNRLevel" with the levels "Low SNR", "Avg SNR", and "High SNR" that I created. "Low SNR" is the same as "SNR_kHz" values below 40. My data is a mixture of numeric, date-time, and categorical data with a lot of NA's due how the data was inherently collected and joined, and consists of a total of ~3000 observations with only ~300 observations that align. I have already binned the data as much as possible and removed NA's where appropriate. One important note is that there are two microphone channels that tell me what the SNR_kHz is ("F.SNRChannel" 1 and 2), and these two channels will always have differing kHz recordings. Channel 1 has shown the lowest kHz values, while Channel 2 seems more stable. I would like to treat these two channels as a single entity if possible as they are physically located right next to each other and as most discrepancies can be due to malfunctions as opposed to actual different kHz recordings. For instance, if "F.SNRChannel 1" falls below 40 kHz, I want the loop to start even if "F.SNRChannel 2" has a kHz value around 70. Below is an image of my dataset "example" and at the bottom of this post is the dput() output of the first 30 rows of my dataset.

[Here is an image of the dataset and its headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8keCQ.png)

While SNR-kHz drops below 40kHzs, I want to to grab the relative humidity and temperature ("Humidmean" and "Tempmean" columns) and the date-time ("binned" column). My date-time column is in the format "2020-08-01 00:06:00." I want to "break" the loop when SNR_kHz gets back above 40 and take note of the date-time, humidity, and temperature again. Typically, when SNR_khz falls below 40, it takes numerous hours or even days to recover above 40 again. I am trying to find the average "time" it takes to do this recovery while also grabbing what the relative humidity and temperature is when the recovery happens. Then I would probably want to take the average of these relative humidity and temperature for all of the loops to infer how long it takes for SNR_khz values to recover for this particular dataset and site.

I have played around with the functions "for", "repeat", "while", "print", "for" "break" and creating new variables inside the loop for what the date-time is when the SNR values drop below 40 (e.g. "start) and what the date-time is when the SNR values are above 40 again (e.g. "end") to use "difftime(end-start)" as a function inside the loop to no avail. Here is an example of code I have tried:

```
repeat{
  
    if(example$SNRLevel=="Low SNR")
      start<-print(example$binned)
      print(example$Humidmean)
    
    if(example$SNRLevel!="Low SNR")
      {
      break
      end<-print(example$binned)
      }
      print(difftime(start-end, tz="America/Chicago", units="hours"))
  }
```

Here is the dput() output of my dataset:

```
>dput(example[495:535, ])
structure(list(binned = structure(c(1597578360, 1597578360, 1597579560, 
1597622760, 1597623960, 1597623960, 1597625160, 1597626360, 1597627560, 
1597628760, 1597629960, 1597631160, 1597632360, 1597633560, 1597634760, 
1597635960, 1597637160, 1597638360, 1597639560, 1597640760, 1597641960, 
1597643160, 1597644360, 1597645560, 1597646760, 1597647960, 1597649160, 
1597650360, 1597651560, 1597652760, 1597653960, 1597655160, 1597656360, 
1597657560, 1597658760, 1597659960, 1597661160, 1597662360, 1597663560, 
1597664760, 1597664760), tzone = "America/Chicago", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), precipsum = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Humidmean = c(64.3, 64.3, 66, 48.8, 
53.1, 53.1, 54.05, 51.4, 55.1, 59.85, 59.6, 57.7, 56.85, 58.8, 
59, 59.2, 57.8, 59.1, 59.45, 62.2, 63.5, 65, 66, 67.6, 67.75, 
70.2, 70.9, 71.8, 74.6, 74.1, 76.5, 74.1, 77, 76.3, 78.3, 81.7, 
90.95, 100, 100, 100, 100), Pressmean = c(980.35, 980.35, 980.5, 
978.6, 978.7, 978.7, 978.6, 978.7, 978.5, 978.6, 978.6, 978.7, 
978.55, 978.6, 978.7, 978.55, 978.6, 978.7, 978.85, 978.8, 979, 
979.2, 979, 979, 979.2, 979.2, 979.1, 979.05, 979.2, 979.2, 978.75, 
978.5, 978.4, 978.15, 978.1, 977.9, 977.7, 977.8, 977.6, 977.95, 
977.95), Tempmean = c(21.6, 21.6, 21.6, 28.5, 27.9, 27.9, 27.5, 
27.5, 27.3, 26.75, 26.5, 26.4, 26.35, 26, 25.7, 25.45, 25.8, 
24.9, 24.7, 24.4, 24.3, 23.9, 23.6, 23.3, 23.3, 23.1, 23, 22.85, 
22.3, 22.5, 21.9, 22.2, 21.7, 22.05, 22, 21.3, 20.45, 19.7, 19.3, 
19.05, 19.05), F.SNRChannel = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2"), class = "factor"), 
    SNR_40kHz = c(2, 65, NA, NA, 0, 65, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 73, 63), 
    HumidLevel = c("Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Low Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", "Avg Humid", 
    "Avg Humid", "High Humid", "High Humid", "High Humid", "High Humid", 
    "High Humid", "High Humid"), SNRLevel = c("Low SNR", "Avg SNR", 
    NA, NA, "Low SNR", "Avg SNR", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "High SNR", "Avg SNR"
    ), RainPresence = c("No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", "No rain", 
    "No rain")), row.names = c(NA, -41L), groups = structure(list(
    binned = structure(c(1597578360, 1597579560, 1597622760, 
    1597623960, 1597625160, 1597626360, 1597627560, 1597628760, 
    1597629960, 1597631160, 1597632360, 1597633560, 1597634760, 
    1597635960, 1597637160, 1597638360, 1597639560, 1597640760, 
    1597641960, 1597643160, 1597644360, 1597645560, 1597646760, 
    1597647960, 1597649160, 1597650360, 1597651560, 1597652760, 
    1597653960, 1597655160, 1597656360, 1597657560, 1597658760, 
    1597659960, 1597661160, 1597662360, 1597663560, 1597664760
    ), tzone = "America/Chicago", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3L, 4L, 5:6, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
        32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40:41), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You want to know the date time when `SNRLevel` starts to be equal to `"Low SNR"` and when it leaves that state, then compute the difftime, then compute the average difftime?

Comment: More or less, yes. I dont necessarily need to find the average difftime in the loop but can rather compute that outside in separate calculations. I am looking for a "model-esque" function that I can eventually predict or expect to see in future datasets. For instance, it might take an average of 5 days for SNRLevel to become normal again (we use 40 as the minimum threshold for microphone sensitivity and anything below 40 is considered very poor microphone readings), and researches would like to know what was the relative humidity and temperature that coincided with that "recovery window."